# does google cloud debugger (stackdriver) support ubuntu 16.04.1 java debugging?

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

to use the google stackdriver debugger with java the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java) says it requires a   64-Bit-Debian-Linux-Image. Is an ubuntu 16.04.1 supported as well ?
There is no error message in the log files, but the application doesn't appear in googles debugger page after supplying the parameters:

```
 -agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so
 -Dcom.google.cdbg.module=MODULE
 -Dcom.google.cdbg.version=VERSION
 -Dcom.google.cdbg.auth.serviceaccount.enable=true
 -Dcom.google.cdbg.auth.serviceaccount.jsonfile=/opt/cdbg/gcp-svc.json
```

does the compute engine vm need additional firewall rules to get the debugger to work ?
best regards,
  noirabys

Comment: That's a good question.  On the surface, my answer would be no.  It wouldn't do any harm to ask Google through support for confirmation/clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is based off of Debian, so you should be good to go.